# show login form in a page in joomla 1.5 programmatically

Tags: php, joomla1.5, jform

Though depreciated. still, I want to achieve this functionality and please don't advise me to upgrade to newer version of Joomla. I have tried to write this piece of code in required place in `/tmp/default.php` file of a particular component. Please advise me am I going right. I have still not got the answer. Thanks.

```
jimport('joomla.form.form');
JModel::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_user'.DS.'models');
$model = JModel::getInstance('User', 'UserModel');
echo "something is not right. Please login.";
var_dump($model);
$form = $model->getLoginForm();
```

Answer (score 2):

To include any module any where this code will be handy.

```
    <?php
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_login');
        //get and update params
        $params = new JRegistry;
        $params->loadString($module->params);
        //$params->set('param','value');
        //render module
        $renderer = $doc->loadRenderer('module');
        $content = $renderer->render($module, array('params'=> $params));
        print $content;
    ?>
```